# Move one column to the left inside a formula using Excel's vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have some cells that contain the following formulas (there are a lot more but I'm just showing one as an example, they all follow the same pattern of using basic operations like + or - with the values inside certain cells)

```
=+$O11+$N11+$M11
```

and I need to move every column one to the left as to end up with something like

```
=+$N11+$M11+$L11
```

the thing is that I have already written code that detects whether or not a cell has a formula or only a value

```
for each cell in Selection // im using a selection for testing purposes only
   if cell.hasFormula() = true then
   end if
next cell
```

but I'm still figuring out how to shift all the column references one to the left, the only code I have written trying to do that does not work

```
auxiliary = "=offset(" + Replace(cell.formula, "=","") + ",0,1)"
cell.formula = auxiliary
```

### Update 1

There are formulas that only use 1 cell to check either if its set or not, up to 8 referenced cells. Numbers or references move around those 2 previously stated numbers

### Update 2

I found the following property named Precedents that is returning the range of references, at least that's what doing if I apply it to a formulated reference i.e with the first example, precedents would return $O$11:$M$11

### Update 3

There are two more types of formulas besides the one stated above, the first is formulas with a Sum i.e.

```
=Sum($R20:$AC20)
```

And with IFs i.e.

```
=IF($BG20=0,1," ")
```

All of the cell references inside of this formulas must be shifted to the Left by 1.

Comment: Does each formula use three reference cells? Are the formulas in the same column?

Comment: No, there are formulas that only use 1 cell to check either if its set or not, or others that use up to 8 reference cells, will update the post accordingly

Comment: You are moving one to the left in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up SJR, fixed it :), the example is correct it must go to the left but i dont know why i wrote Right.

Comment: I think you need to provide more examples. Are all the formula just one or more cell addresses separated by + or - signs? Do they all have dollar signs? Could there be brackets etc?

Comment: I added 2 more examples, but those are all the types of formulas that exists, Sums ifs and plain old addresses separated by + or - signs, all of the hame dollar signs, no brackets in any of them

Comment: On reflection, the variation probably doesn't matter too much if you are just shifting columns. I'll take a look later when I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you are overwriting the same cell, you can try:

```
Option Explicit
Sub shiftLeft()
    Dim f As String
    Dim origCol As Long, newCol As Long
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Dim re As Object, mc As Object, m As Object
    Dim I As Long, startNum As Long, numChars As Long

Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With re
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "C\[?(-?\d+)"
End With

Set r = Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp))
For Each c In r
    If c.HasFormula = True Then
        f = c.FormulaR1C1
        'Debug.Print f, c.Formula
        If re.test(f) = True Then
            Set mc = re.Execute(f)
            For I = mc.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set m = mc(I - 1)
                startNum = m.firstindex + 1 + Len(m) - Len(m.submatches(0))
                numChars = Len(m.submatches(0))
                newCol = m.submatches(0) - 1
                f = WorksheetFunction.Replace(f, startNum, numChars, newCol)
            Next I
        End If
    End If
    c.FormulaR1C1 = f
    'Debug.Print f, c.Formula & vbLf
Next c

End Sub
```

I use regular expressions to find the column designation which will be in the form of `Cnn` or `C[nn]` or `C[-nn]`
We can then subtract one from `nn` to get the new column number
Use the location and length to decide where to place the replacement.

If the resultant formula refers to a column to the left of column `A`, this macro will terminate with a run-time error `1004`.  You should probably add a routine depending on what you want to do in that instance.

**EDIT:** *I did not test to ensure that `Cnn` is a valid cell address and not a `NAME`.  Mostly that won't matter unless  you have some very unusual names (eg `Cnnnnnnnnn`) since names that conflict with cell addresses will be rejected, but if your `C` is followed by a large number, it may be accepted. That test could be added if it might be an issue.*

Comment: I will test your code as soon as i can, also about the a column, it will never be near a, the formulas are all starting on the o column to the right :)

Comment: Your code works like a charm, can i ask you what exactly is vbscript.regexp? is this like exclusively for regular expresions?

Also, i have done some regular expresions check on PHP, does it work somewhat alike to php regular expressions?

Sorry if thats a lot of question, also Thank you very much for the answer works like a Charm!

Comment: @Magthuzad It late-binds the vbscript regex dll.  Vbscript regex is based on the Java flavor.  There are some differences from the php flavor; you can find references to the different flavors on the 'net.  MS Help for vba regular expressions, and elsewhere, will acquaint you with the methods and properties.  Glad the code was useful.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a helper temporary sheet to copy/paste data/formula to, delete first column (and have formula shift one column left) and paste back:

```
Dim tmpSht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Selection
Set tmpSht = Worksheets.Add
With rng
    .Copy Destination:=tmpSht.Range(rng.Address).Offset(, -1)
End With

With tmpSht
    .Columns(1).Delete
    .Range(rng.Address).Offset(, -2).Copy Destination:=rng
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```

---

or you could act on every single cell with formula:

```
Sub main()
    Dim tmpSht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

    Set rng = Selection
    Set tmpSht = Worksheets.Add ' add a "helper" temporary worksheet

    For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) ' loop through selection cells containing a formula
        ShiftFormulaOneColumnToTheLeft cell, tmpSht
    Next

    'delete "helper" worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub ShiftFormulaOneColumnToTheLeft(rng As Range, hlpSht As Worksheet)
    rng.Copy Destination:=hlpSht.Range("B1") ' copy passed range and paste it to passed "helper" worksheet range "B1"

    With hlpSht ' reference passed "helper" worksheet
        .Columns(1).Delete ' delete referenced worksheet first column and have all its formulas shift one column to the left
        .Range("A1").Copy Destination:=rng ' copy "helper" worksheet "A1" cell (where previous "B1" has ended to) content  to passed range
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work to move/shift the formula's references as intended:

```
strFormula$ = "=+$O11+$N11+$M11"
strFormulaMoved$ = Application.ConvertFormula(Application.ConvertFormula(Selection.Formula, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, XlReferenceType.xlRelative, Selection), XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, XlReferenceType.xlRelRowAbsColumn, Selection.Offset(0, -1))
```