# VBA on conditionally formatted cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to calculate a cell base on a cell which is conditionally formatted.

I've use IF statement to calculate the price per box if the ICO (ICO is our term for average order per 3 months) is Conditionally formatted (I use gray color and bold it to diplay that it is in Case and not per piece) , if it's not bold the cell must calculate the price per piece.   I've tried using the VBA that returns the value True or False if the selected cell is conditionally formatted even if the condition is not met. You have any idea how to display true or false if the condition is met by the cell?  [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366145/vba-function-to-test-if-cell-is-conditionally-formatted-in-excel

Comment: Copy the formula from conditional formatting and enter into a helper column/row.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/338-Get-Displayed-Cell-Color-(whether-from-Conditional-Formatting-or-not). After that you may prefer to look for a solution which doesn't look as easy as reading the cell colour. :-)

Comment: what does `cell base` mean?

Comment: @jsotola Hi, I just meant based on a cell

Comment: Hi @Variatus thank you for the link will read it now

Comment: Hi @ian0411 there is a multiple condition on my ICO, it is based on the account name.. should I need to upload the file please tell me.. thank you so much

Comment: See this pic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec0L9.png), you can find the column C is a helper column that has a formula copied from conditional formatting.  This way I know it will return true of false.  You can remove that after you have verified your test cases.  But let me know if this is not clear.  Or you can upload the screenshots of your settings for us to further assist.