# Change Cell Reference between Absolute and Relative

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want to write a macro which goes through all cell references in a selection's cells **formula** and changes them to **absolute** or **relative**.

Is there a formatting variable which can change this or a function which does this already (similar to what pressing `F4` does) but as a macro.

### Update

I am wondering if this is still current and/or if there are any more updates to also individually select fields, make them relative or absolute individually without resorting to pattern matching the string.

Comment: Wil it not always be absolute when you are looping through a selection of cells? or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @SiddharthRout It's more to do with adjusting the formula in the cell itself so it says $A$1 instead of A1 in all cases within the selection

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now :)

Comment: A formula in a cell can have multiple ranges with multiple formats. Do you want to change all of them? For example `Vlookup($A$1,B10:B30,1,0)`

Comment: Yes, so the above with the Abs formula would be `VLOOKUP($A$1,$B$10:$B$30,1,0)` and with the Rel formula `VLOOKUP(A1,B10:B30,1,0)`

Comment: Then see what @cyboashu has posted

Comment: I have a very complex solution but want to check something with you. When your formula has mixed references as I have shown above with `vLookup` then how will you decide which one do you want? Absolute or Relative?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks, I was just wanting to get the formula to change the reference. I feel bad because you put a lot of work into this but I accepted the first answer because I feel it would also answer the questions more specifically for people with a similar query. I upvoted your answer as it is a good solution though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ConvertFormula` method.

4th Parameter determines whether its absolute or not. 1 sets it to absolute and 4 sets it to relative. As per one comment to this answer, if you are looking for mixed references, then its bit complex. but reading your question and comments, I think that's not what you are after.

```
Examples:
'/ Set it to absolute
ActiveCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(ActiveCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, 1)

'/ Set it to relative
ActiveCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(ActiveCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, 4)
```

Comment: This is part of the answer, how he can decide whether he had absolute or relative references?  (What about formulas with mixed references? )

Comment: ++ Now you need to add just one check to see what kind of formula is it and then use one of the code that you provided

Comment: This works within the workbook however not when the reference is between workbooks. If it can be amended to work with that I'll accept the answer. If there is no other way I'll just accept it though as this is effectively what I was looking for but does not work in my context. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have edited the question but since I have already worked on this, I am posting an answer.

If you do not know what the formula contains and want to change `Relative` to `Absolute` and `Absolute/Mixed` to `Relative` then try this

Let's say I have 4 ranges in my `Selection` as shown below

[image: ![enter image description here]

So I can use `RegEx` as suggested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835466/find-all-used-references-in-excel-formula) to extract individial addresses and find what kind of formula is it and then do the changes as suggested by @cyboashu

```
Const sPattern As String = _
"(['].*?['!])?([[A-Z0-9_]+[!])?(\$?[A-Z]+\$?(\d)+(:\$?[A-Z]+\$?(\d)+)?|\$?[A-Z]+:\$?[A-Z]+|(\$?[A-Z]+\$?(\d)+))"

Sub Sample()
    Dim sMatches As Object, objRex As Object
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim bAbsMix As Boolean, bRel As Boolean

    Set rng = Selection

    Set objRex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With objRex
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With

    For Each aCell In rng
        objRex.Pattern = """.*?"""
        sFormula = aCell.Formula
        sFormula = objRex.Replace(sFormula, "")

        objRex.Pattern = "(([A-Z])+(\d)+)"
        objRex.Pattern = sPattern

        If objRex.test(sFormula) Then
            Set sMatches = objRex.Execute(sFormula)
            If sMatches.Count > 0 Then
                For Each Match In sMatches
                    If Len(Match) = Len(Replace(Match, "$", "")) Then
                        bRel = True
                    Else
                        bAbsMix = True
                    End If
                Next Match
            End If
        End If

        If bAbsMix = True Then  '<~~ It is Absolute/Mixed
            Debug.Print sFormula & " in " & aCell.Address & " is Absolute/Mixed"
            aCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(aCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, 4)
        Else '<~ It is Relative
            Debug.Print sFormula & " in " & aCell.Address & " is Relative"
            aCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(aCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, 1)
        End If

        bRel = False: bAbsMix = False
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

**In Immediate Window**

[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write a macro which goes through all cell references in a selection's cells formula and changes them to absolute or relative.

For conciseness this code works for a single-cell range.  The principle can be extended to a multi-cell range.

> Wondering if this is still current and/or if there are any more updates to also individually select fields, make them relative or absolute individually without resorting to pattern matching the string.

This solution uses the range's `.FormulaLocal` and `.FormulaR1C1` properties to switch between absolute and relative references.

```
Private Sub ChangeReferenceType(cellRange As Range)

    ' This sub works with a 1 cell range

    ' Row and column of the range
    Dim cellRow As Long, cellColumn As Long
    cellRow = cellRange.row
    cellColumn = cellRange.column
    
    ' Is the cell using absolute or relative formulas?
    Dim absolute As Boolean
    absolute = False
    If InStr(1, cellRange.FormulaLocal, "$") > 0 Then
        absolute = True
    End If
    
    Dim newFormula As String
    
    If absolute Then
        ' Making a formula relative is simple:
        ' Remove all the $
        newFormula = Replace(cellRange.FormulaLocal, "$", "")
                
    Else
        ' Making a formula absolute is more involved:
        ' - Find each relaitve row and column reference
        ' - Calculate the absolute location of each one
        ' - Replace the relative references with absolute
                
        newFormula = cellRange.FormulaR1C1
        
        Dim startPosition As Long, endPosition As Long, extract As String, number As Long, row As Long, column As Long
        
        ' Replace rows
        Do While InStr(1, newFormula, "R[") > 0
        
            startPosition = InStr(1, newFormula, "R[")
            endPosition = InStr(1, newFormula, "]")
            
            extract = Mid(newFormula, startPosition, endPosition - startPosition + 1)
            number = CLng(Replace(Replace(extract, "R[", ""), "]", ""))
            row = cellRow + number
            
            newFormula = Replace(newFormula, extract, "R" & row)
        
        Loop
        
        ' Replace columns
        Do While InStr(1, newFormula, "C[") > 0
        
            startPosition = InStr(1, newFormula, "C[")
            endPosition = InStr(1, newFormula, "]")
        
            extract = Mid(newFormula, startPosition, endPosition - startPosition + 1)
            number = CLng(Replace(Replace(extract, "C[", ""), "]", ""))
            column = cellColumn + number
        
            newFormula = Replace(newFormula, extract, "C" & column)
        
        Loop
                
    End If
    
    ' Write the new formula to the cell
    cellRange.FormulaLocal = newFormula
    
End Sub
```

Consider an example: the cell B2 has the formula `=A1` written in it.  This formula is relative, and thus has the following `FormulaR1C1`: "=R[-1]C[-1]".  These [#] values are the difference between the cell's location, and the reference's location.

Say cell B2 has the formula `=$A$1` written in it.  The `FormulaR1C1` value is: `=R1C1`.  Here, the numbers are the actual row and column number.

Now, we can use the presence of "R[" and "C[" to inform if a cell's `FormulaR1C1` has any relative references in it.  Loop through your cell's formula and replace these relative references with absolute ones to get a fully absolute formula.

Converting the formula to fully relative is a lot easier: just remove the `$` from the `FormulaLocal`!