# Change multiple cell references from relative to absolute ($) at once

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following values and formulas in my Excel spreadsheet:

```
          A                             
1      Shirt         =Sheet2!A2
2        50          =C1
3       350          =Sheet3!D7
4    Product B       =F8
5
6
```

The values in **Column A** I get from other parts of the Excel file by using **only** relative cell references.

Now I want to change those cell references from relative to **absolute** so they look like this:

```
          A                             
1      Shirt         =Sheet2!$A$2
2        50          =$C$1
3       350          =Sheet3!$D$7
4    Product B       =$F$8
5
6
```

Therefore, I tried to go with the VBA from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821608/change-cell-reference-between-absolute-and-relative):

```
Sub Test()
ActiveCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(ActiveCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, 1)
End Sub
```

However, it only works for the active cell but I want that the VBA goes through the entire sheet. Therefore, I was trying something like this:

```
Sub Test()
Sheet1.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(Sheet1.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, 1)
End Sub
```

Now I get the error "Object or method not found".
How do I have to change the VBA to make it work?

Comment: Maybe `ActiveSheet.Cells.Formula` instead of `Sheet1.Formula` would work? But I'm not pretty sure if all formulas can be converted at once.

Comment: Tried it but now I get runtime error 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing this at once will not be possible. A kind of loop over the single formula cells is needed.

You can get special cells using [Range.SpecialCells Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel). Thus you can get all formula cells and then do looping over them and converting them to absolute:

```
Sub convertAllSheetFormulasToAbsolute()
 Dim oCell As Range
 With ActiveSheet
  For Each oCell In .Cells.SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeFormulas)
   oCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(oCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, xlAbsolute)
  Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change just the selected cells (not all formulas in the entire sheet), use the following macro:

```
Sub Formulas_To_AbsoluteReference()
 Dim oCell As Range
 With Selection
  For Each oCell In .Cells.SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeFormulas)
   oCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(oCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, xlAbsolute)
  Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Some similar macros:

```
Sub Formulas_To_LockRowNumber_RelColumnLetter()
 Dim oCell As Range
 With Selection
  For Each oCell In .Cells.SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeFormulas)
   oCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(oCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, xlAbsRowRelColumn)
  Next
 End With
End Sub


Sub FormulasTo_LockColLetter_RelRowNum()
 Dim oCell As Range
 With Selection
  For Each oCell In .Cells.SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeFormulas)
   oCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(oCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, xlRelRowAbsColumn)
  Next
 End With
End Sub


Sub FormulasTo_AllRelative_Reference()
 Dim oCell As Range
 With Selection
  For Each oCell In .Cells.SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeFormulas)
   oCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(oCell.Formula, xlA1, xlA1, xlRelative)
  Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice collection - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, the [ASAP Utilities for Excel](https://www.asap-utilities.com/index.php) add-in provides a menu command that converts your selected range of cells to absolute references, mixed references, or relative references. It's worked flawlessly for me for years.

Once you have the add-in installed, in the Formulas menu, select "Change formula reference style (e.g. A1 to $A1, etc.).