# How to get the address of a cell in $A$1 form

Tags: excel, office-js

I am using office JS to create a Excel Web Addin. I want to get the address of a cell in $A$1 form.

Right now I am using the address property of Excel.Range which gives the address like Sheet1!A1. How do I fetch it as Sheet1!$A$1?

Following is the code I use to load address property.

```
var activeCell = context.workbook.getActiveCell();
activeCell.load("address");
```

Comment: Convert is as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821608/change-cell-reference-between-absolute-and-relative

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I am looking for a way to do this with Office JS, not VSTO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to add the dollar signs before the column letters and row number.

Here's something that I think should work. Here `$1` matches `Sheet1!`, `$2` matches the column letters, `$3` matches the row numbers, and `$$` is to put a literal dollar sign in the result.

```
var res = str.replace(/(.*\!)(\D+)(\d+)/g, "$1$$$2$$$3");
```