# ActiveCell.Formula Error 1004 - Very Simple

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a 1004 Error when I run the below code. Sometimes it works but many times it breaks on the ActiveCell.Formula Line. I can't understand why it does and does not work sometimes.

I am looking to input "$" into the existing formulas for a bunch of cells.

Code:

```
Dim Orig_Formula As String

Orig_Formula = ActiveCell.Formula

Orig_Formula = Mid(Orig_Formula, 1, 31) & "$" & Mid(Orig_Formula, 32, 1) & "$" & Mid(Orig_Formula, 33)

ActiveCell.Formula = Orig_Formula

ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Activate
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You may be reinventing the wheel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821608/change-cell-reference-between-absolute-and-relative

Comment: `Debug.Print Orig_Formula` then try pasting it into a cell - what error do you get?

Comment: No Error, In the immediate window, the String is concatenated correctly - "=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet3!B4),Sheet3!$A$4,0)"

I'll look into the convert formula function, thank you.

Comment: `Orig_Formula = ActiveCell.Formula` What is the original formula?

Comment: The Formula stored in the cells are VLookups. "=Vlookup(B2, Sheet!1 Etc..)"

I realized that this is not the correct approach however since I am referencing the target $ locations absolutely while it should be relatively referenced. The local variable should still be recognized by ActiveCell.Formula though I believe.