# Trace precedents and document target/source worksheet cell references of user defined cell input

Tags: vba, excel

The following code traces back all precedents (or only current precedents, depending on whether you select the Boolean to be True or False) for a cell selected by the user. I am running the output to a new sheet called "Precedents", and currently only two columns are populated with the "Worksheet" and "Cell" precedent values. I have a need to add two more columns in this output to define the "Target Worksheet" and "Target Cell".

I am struggling to understand how to offset the Activecell (code is in the last few lines of the ZoomToPrecedents Sub) so that I can create two new columns and basically just store the cell name and worksheet name of the "target" cell (for example, "target" cell is the one the user picks to trace its precedents). The current output is displaying the "source" cells (precedents of target cell which are contained within the formula of the target cell). These four columns of source worksheet, source cell, target worksheet, and target cell will help me see which source cells are being used to create the target cell. Please let me know if you can help me to create this. I really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
Sub ZoomToPrecedents()
' based off of https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/

' accessed 8/11/15

    Dim boolAllLevels As Boolean

    ' if you'd like to show all levels of dependency (this cell depends on this cell which depends on this cell which depends on this cell)
    ' set boolAllLevels to True
    ' I wouldn't recommend showing all levels of dependency for complex models - the message box will get really long
    '
    ' if you'd like to only show the current cell's dependencies
    ' set boolAllLevels to False
    ' by default boolAllLevels will be set to False
    boolAllLevels = False

    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim dicAllPrecedents As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strNoPrecedentsMsg As String
    Dim strPrecedentsListMsg As String
    Dim iGoToPrecedent As Integer
    Dim strGoToPrecedent As String
    Dim strGoToWorksheet As String
    Dim strGoToRange As String
    Dim iExclamPosition As Integer
    Dim iBracketPosition As Integer
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim strWorkbookFileName As String
    Dim strWorksheetName As String
    Dim strGoToWorkbook As String

    Set rngToCheck = ActiveCell
    Set dicAllPrecedents = GetAllPrecedents(rngToCheck)

    strWorkbookFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    strWorksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

    If dicAllPrecedents.Count = 0 Then
         strToCheckNoPrecedents = rngToCheck.Address(External:=True) & " has no precedent cells."
         MsgBox strPrecedentsListMsg, vbOKOnly, "No Precedents"
    Else
        For i = LBound(dicAllPrecedents.Keys) To UBound(dicAllPrecedents.Keys)
            If dicAllPrecedents.Items()(i) = 1 Or boolAllLevels Then
                strGoToPrecedent = dicAllPrecedents.Keys()(i)
                If Not InStr(1, strGoToPrecedent, strWorkbookFileName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    iBracketPosition = InStr(1, strGoToPrecedent, "]", vbTextCompare)
                    iGoToPrecedentLength = Len(strGoToPrecedent)
                    j = iGoToPrecedentLength - iBracketPosition
                    strGoToPrecedent = Right(strGoToPrecedent, j)
                    strGoToPrecedent = "'" & strGoToPrecedent

                    If Not InStr(1, strGoToPrecedent, strWorksheetName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        iExclamationPosition = InStr(1, strGoToPrecedent, "!", vbTextCompare)
                        iGoToPrecedentLength = Len(strGoToPrecedent)
                        j = iGoToPrecedentLength - iExclamationPosition
                        strGoToPrecedent = Right(strGoToPrecedent, j)
                    End If
                End If
                strPrecedentsListMsg = strPrecedentsListMsg & i & ": "
                If boolAllLevels Then
                    strPrecedentsListMsg = strPrecedentsListMsg & "(Level " & dicAllPrecedents.Items()(i) & ") "
                End If
                strPrecedentsListMsg = strPrecedentsListMsg & strGoToPrecedent & Chr(10)
            End If
        Next i

        ' 9/5/2017 additions ***************************************************************
        '
        '

        ' Add new worksheet
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Precedents"

        ' Add column headers
        Sheets("Precedents").Activate
        Range("A1").Value = "Worksheet"
        Range("B1").Value = "Cell"
        Range("C1").Value = "Target Worksheet"
        Range("D1").Value = "Target Cell"
        ' Write precedents list
        Dim strCurPrecedent As String
        Dim iCurPrecedentLength As Integer
        Dim iCurRange As Range
        Dim strCurWorksheet As String
        Dim strTargetWorksheet As String
        Dim strTargetCell As Range

        Range("A2").Activate
        For i = LBound(dicAllPrecedents.Keys) To UBound(dicAllPrecedents.Keys)

            If dicAllPrecedents.Items()(i) = 1 Or boolAllLevels Then


                strCurPrecedent = dicAllPrecedents.Keys()(i)

                iExclamationPosition = InStr(1, strCurPrecedent, "!", vbTextCompare)
                iBracketPosition = InStr(1, strCurPrecedent, "]", vbTextCompare)
                iCurPrecedentLength = Len(strCurPrecedent)

                j = iBracketPosition - 3
                strCurWorkbook = Mid(strCurPrecedent, 3, j)

                j = iCurPrecedentLength - iExclamationPosition
                strCurRange = Right(strCurPrecedent, j)

                j = iBracketPosition + 1
                k = iExclamationPosition - j - 1
                strCurWorksheet = Mid(strCurPrecedent, j, k)

                ActiveCell.Value = strCurWorksheet
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                ActiveCell.Value = strCurRange
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate\


            End If

        Next I
***************************************************************

        ' 9/5/2017 removals ***************************************************************
        '
        '

'        iGoToPrecedent = InputBox(strPrecedentsListMsg, "Go To Precedent", "Enter line number from above")
'        strGoToPrecedent = dicAllPrecedents.Keys()(iGoToPrecedent)
'
'        iExclamationPosition = InStr(1, strGoToPrecedent, "!", vbTextCompare)
'        iBracketPosition = InStr(1, strGoToPrecedent, "]", vbTextCompare)
'        iGoToPrecedentLength = Len(strGoToPrecedent)
'
'        j = iBracketPosition - 3
'        strGoToWorkbook = Mid(strGoToPrecedent, 3, j)
'
'        j = iGoToPrecedentLength - iExclamationPosition
'        strGoToRange = Right(strGoToPrecedent, j)
'
'        j = iBracketPosition + 1
'        k = iExclamationPosition - j - 1
'        strGoToWorksheet = Mid(strGoToPrecedent, j, k)
'
'        Application.GoTo Reference:=Workbooks(strGoToWorkbook).Worksheets(strGoToWorksheet).Range(strGoToRange)

        ' End of 9/5/2017 removals ***************************************************************
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetAllPrecedents(ByRef rngToCheck As Range) As Object
' courtesy of https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/
' accessed 8/11/15
' won't navigate through precedents in closed workbooks
' won't navigate through precedents in protected worksheets
' won't identify precedents on hidden sheets

    Const lngTOP_LEVEL As Long = 1
    Dim dicAllPrecedents As Object
    Dim strKey As String

    Set dicAllPrecedents = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    GetPrecedents rngToCheck, dicAllPrecedents, lngTOP_LEVEL
    Set GetAllPrecedents = dicAllPrecedents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function

Private Sub GetPrecedents(ByRef rngToCheck As Range, ByRef dicAllPrecedents As Object, ByVal lngLevel As Long)
' courtesy of https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/
' accessed 8/11/15

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngFormulas As Range

    If Not rngToCheck.Worksheet.ProtectContents Then
        If rngToCheck.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then   'Change to .Count in XL 2003 or earlier
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngFormulas = rngToCheck.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            If rngToCheck.HasFormula Then Set rngFormulas = rngToCheck
        End If

        '
        If Not rngFormulas Is Nothing Then
            For Each rngCell In rngFormulas.Cells
                GetCellPrecedents rngCell, dicAllPrecedents, lngLevel
            Next rngCell
            rngFormulas.Worksheet.ClearArrows
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub GetCellPrecedents(ByRef rngCell As Range, ByRef dicAllPrecedents As Object, ByVal lngLevel As Long)
' courtesy of https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/
' accessed 8/11/15

    Dim lngArrow As Long
    Dim lngLink As Long
    Dim blnNewArrow As Boolean
    Dim strPrecedentAddress As String
    Dim rngPrecedentRange As Range

    Do
        lngArrow = lngArrow + 1
        blnNewArrow = True
        lngLink = 0

        Do
            lngLink = lngLink + 1

            rngCell.ShowPrecedents

            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngPrecedentRange = rngCell.NavigateArrow(True, lngArrow, lngLink)

            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            On Error GoTo 0
            strPrecedentAddress = rngPrecedentRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, True)

            If strPrecedentAddress = rngCell.Address(False, False, xlA1, True) Then
                Exit Do
            Else

                blnNewArrow = False

                If Not dicAllPrecedents.Exists(strPrecedentAddress) Then
                    dicAllPrecedents.Add strPrecedentAddress, lngLevel
                    GetPrecedents rngPrecedentRange, dicAllPrecedents, lngLevel + 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        If blnNewArrow Then Exit Do
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[VBA: Determine All Precedent Cells – A Nice Example Of Recursion](https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/)

I used Michael Møldrup answer to [Find all used references in Excel formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835466/find-all-used-references-in-excel-formula) to extract the Precedents from the formulas without use `ShowPrecedents`.

### Output

```
Level   Workbook    Worksheet   Cell.Address    Formula Value
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$1    =INDIRECT("B1") 1
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$2    =SUM(B2,Sheet2!A2)  8
1   Precedents.xlsm Sheet2  $A$2    =SUM(B2,Sheet3!A2)  6
2   Precedents.xlsm Sheet3  $A$2    =SUM(B2:C2) 4
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$3    =SUM(B3,Sheet2!A3)  12
1   Precedents.xlsm Sheet2  $A$3    =SUM(B3,Sheet3!A3)  9
2   Precedents.xlsm Sheet3  $A$3    =SUM(B3:C3) 6
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$4    =SUM(B4,Sheet2!A4)  16
1   Precedents.xlsm Sheet2  $A$4    =SUM(B4,Sheet3!A4)  12
2   Precedents.xlsm Sheet3  $A$4    =SUM(B4:C4) 8
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$5    =SUM(B5,Sheet2!A5)  20
1   Precedents.xlsm Sheet2  $A$5    =SUM(B5,Sheet3!A5)  15
2   Precedents.xlsm Sheet3  $A$5    =SUM(B5:C5) 10
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$6    =SUM(B6,Sheet2!A6)  24
1   Precedents.xlsm Sheet2  $A$6    =SUM(B6,Sheet3!A6)  18
2   Precedents.xlsm Sheet3  $A$6    =SUM(B6:C6) 12
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$7    =SUM(B7,Sheet2!A7)  28
1   Precedents.xlsm Sheet2  $A$7    =SUM(B7,Sheet3!A7)  21
2   Precedents.xlsm Sheet3  $A$7    =SUM(B7:C7) 14
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$8    =SUM(B8,Sheet2!A8)  32
1   Precedents.xlsm Sheet2  $A$8    =SUM(B8,Sheet3!A8)  24
2   Precedents.xlsm Sheet3  $A$8    =SUM(B8:C8) 16
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$9    =SUM(B9,Sheet2!A9)  36
1   Precedents.xlsm Sheet2  $A$9    =SUM(B9,Sheet3!A9)  27
2   Precedents.xlsm Sheet3  $A$9    =SUM(B9:C9) 18
0   Precedents.xlsm Sheet1  $A$10   =SUM(B10,Sheet2!A10)    40
1   Precedents.xlsm Sheet2  $A$10   =SUM(B10,Sheet3!A10)    30
2   Precedents.xlsm Sheet3  $A$10   =SUM(B10:C10)   20
```

Code:

```
Sub Test_ListPrecedents()
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim Target As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Target = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    result = getPrecedentsInfo(Target)

    If IsMissing(result) Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Precedents").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        .Name = "Precedents"
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(result), UBound(result, 2)).Value = result
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub

Function getPrecedentsInfo(Target As Range) As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim PrecedentsList As Object
    Set PrecedentsList = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")

    FillPrecedentsList Target, PrecedentsList

    If PrecedentsList.Count > 0 Then
        PrecedentsList.Insert 0, Array("Level", "Workbook", "Worksheet", "Cell.Address", "Formula", "Value")
        result = PrecedentsList.ToArray
        result = Application.Transpose(result)
        result = Application.Transpose(result)
        getPrecedentsInfo = result
    End If
End Function

Sub FillPrecedentsList(Target As Range, Optional PrecedentsList As Object, Optional objRegEx As Object, Optional Level As Long)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim testExpression As String

    If objRegEx Is Nothing Then
        Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
        objRegEx.Global = True
    End If

    For Each cell In Target
        objRegEx.Pattern = """.*?"""                  ' remove expressions

        If cell.HasFormula Then
            testExpression = CStr(cell.Formula)
            testExpression = objRegEx.Replace(testExpression, "")
            objRegEx.Pattern = "(([A-Z])+(\d)+)"      'grab the address
            objRegEx.Pattern = "(['].*?['!])?([[A-Z0-9_]+[!])?(\$?[A-Z]+\$?(\d)+(:\$?[A-Z]+\$?(\d)+)?|\$?[A-Z]+:\$?[A-Z]+|(\$?[A-Z]+\$?(\d)+))"
            PrecedentsList.Add Array(Level, cell.Parent.Parent.Name, cell.Parent.Name, cell.Address, "'" & cell.Formula, cell.Value)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If objRegEx.Test(testExpression) Then
            Set result = objRegEx.Execute(testExpression)
            If result.Count > 0 Then
                For Each Match In result
                    FillPrecedentsList Range(Match.Value), PrecedentsList, objRegEx, Level + 1
                Next Match
            End If
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```